# Html input's name in div select Angular 2.1.4

Tags: html, angular

is there any way in angular 2 to pick name/id of input inside divs?

html:

```
<div class="form-pages" (click)='function()'>//if it's possible then what should I put into function param?
    <fieldset>
     <input type="text" name="firstName"/>
     <input type="text" name="firstName"/>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

component:
`function(str){this.var=str}`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if template variables of child elements can be accessed

```
<div class="form-pages" (click)='function(input1.value, input2.value)'>//if it's possible then what should I put into function param?
    <fieldset>
     <input #input1 type="text" name="firstName"/>
     <input #input2 type="text" name="firstName"/>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

If this doesn't work you can use

```
<div class="form-pages" (click)='function()'>//if it's possible then what should I put into function param?
    <fieldset>
     <input #myinput type="text" name="firstName"/>
     <input #myinput type="text" name="firstName"/>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

```
@ViewChildren('input') inputs:QueryList<ElementRef>;

myFunction() {
  let inputs = this.inputs.toArray();
  console.log(inputs[0].value;
  console.log(inputs[1].value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I did it alone, thanks for previous answer, but for me it works well, It's needed to call $event.target.name method which will return name of clicked target.

```
<div (click)="setFocus($event.target.name)">
<input type='text' name='input1 />
<input type='text' name='input2 />
</div>
```

in component`setFocus(str){this.var = str)`